# Opening a new form without owner?

Tags: c#, winforms, window

I made a C# Windows Forms application that requires the user to login using a form called `Form1` as shown below:

```
// This code is called from Form1

Form2 f = new Form2();
f.Show();

// Then Form1 does some finalization logic and closes itself
```

After the user logs in, the login form should close and the main application window `Form2` should be opened. But the problem I'm running into is that if I call Form2 from Form1, Form1 becomes Form2's owner, thus closing Form1 closes both forms and ends the application.

How may I call Form2 such that it is independent of Form1?

Comment: How is `form1` being shown? Is it via `Application.Run`?

Comment: im using f.Show() as shown above, that is the exact code in visual studio

Comment: I meant `form1`, not `form2`. How is `form1` being shown?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm assuming its the default Main generated code - `Application.Run`

Comment: Oh sorry, yes it is Application.Run(...);

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the owner, but that the Windows message loop is tied to Form1. When Form1 closes, so does the application. Look in your `Main` method:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

The easiest solution is to show your login form (assuming it's a login form) as a modal dialog, and then begin the windows message loop on Form2:

```
static void Main()
{
    var form1 = new Form1();
    form1.ShowDialog();
    if (form1.LoginSuccessful)
    {
        Application.Run(new Form2());
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Just did some googling and looks like another alternative is custom `ApplicationContext`s. Never worked with these myself though:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext.aspx

Comment: I was going to write up an `ApplicationContext` based sample, but can't be bothered now...